# How to add add plist file in Xcode 11.6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

My app needs a boolean value of yes under App Transport Security in the projects plist. The app I'm using doesnt have a plist file. Under packaging in the build settings tab, it says that the projects plsit file is named `iReporter/iReporter-Info.plist`.

When `plist` is searched for on the `show the find navigator tab`, the closest thing that comes up is a file named `InfoPlist.strings`.

How do I add a real editable plist file to Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For every iOS app there must me `Info.plist` file which has the info. about the application in key-value pair.

- If you renamed the `Info.plist` file then you need to rename back to original name.
- Also make sure that the info plist path is correct set in build settings.

[image]

- If you accedentily removed the `Info.plist' file then your project won't compile. You need to create new one or you can copy from the other app and past into your project and set the key-value pair required by your app.

> The `InfoPlist.string` is not the actual info.plist file which is asked by complier. The `.strings` file can be used while localisation is getting integrated into iOS app.